# Ruby method overriding

Tags: ruby

I'm just starting out in Ruby and I've come across a very strange behavior of methods that I can't explain. For example:

```
class String
  def substitute
    gsub("a", "b")
  end
end

puts "aa".substitute # outputs: "bb"
```

How can this be? I don't pass any arguments to the 'substitute' method, how does it know which string to call the `gsub` method on? Is there some invisible attribute before the `gsub` method that can be left out?

Here's how a "usual" method should work, in my mind. It get's an argument and operates on that data. (However, in the previous example, there was no data that `gsub` could operate on?)

```
def substitute(arg)
  arg.gsub("a", "b")
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
class String
  def substitute
    gsub("a", "b")
  end
end
```

is the same as

```
class String
  def substitute
    self.gsub("a", "b")
  end
end
```

That means `gsub` is called on the String instance which is "aa" in your case.

Comment: Thank you, but i'm still a bit confused. Why does 'self' contain the value of the string? Shouldn't self be just an object reference? I'm assuming here that the value of the string is contained in the instance of a String class (they're not the same thing). What am i not getting ?

Comment: @geekkid `String` instance's `self` is a mutable String object with allocated memory of its own. It is not just a reference or pointer. You can call functions which mutate the memory it owns. Same with `Array`. But, for example, `Fixnum` is not mutable which means self= 42 wouldn't work.

Answer (score -1):

In your example

```
puts "aa".substitute # outputs: "bb"
```

The `"aa"` **object** is an instance of the **class** String. Objects know their contents or data and their class.

Because the `"aa"` object knows it is a String, you can call the method `#substitute` on it, which is defined in String.

Because the `"aa"` object knows it's contents or data, `#substitute` needs no argument to modify this data.